# Blockchain Websocket in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a program in java for websocket for blockchain.
My this example is working well :

`
import java.io.*;
import com.neovisionaries.ws.client.*;

```
public class Test
{
private static final String SERVER = "wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv";
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    WebSocket ws = connect();
    ws.sendText("{\"op\":\"unconfirmed_sub\"}");
}

private static WebSocket connect() throws IOException, WebSocketException
{
    return new WebSocketFactory().setConnectionTimeout(500000000).createSocket(SERVER)
            .addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
                public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) {
                    System.out.println(message);
                }
            })
            .connect();
}
} `
```

but not this one :

```
`
import java.io.*; 
import com.neovisionaries.ws.client.*;

public class Test
{
private static final String SERVER = "wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv";
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    WebSocket ws = connect();
    ws.sendText("{\"op\":\"addr_sub\", \"addr\":\"65SQr6sh9SeS39PRbw8PHGp9wpv39\"}");
}

private static WebSocket connect() throws IOException, WebSocketException
{
    return new WebSocketFactory().setConnectionTimeout(500000000).createSocket(SERVER)
            .addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
                public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) {
                    System.out.println(message);
                }
            })
            .connect();
 } 
}`
```

Same way in jquery it is working, but not in java

Comment: Please clarify _what_ is _not working_, do you get any meaningful error message to share? The difference between the two snippets is only in the submittted requests: `"{\"op\":\"unconfirmed_sub\"}"` vs. `"{\"op\":\"addr_sub\", \"addr\":\"65SQr6sh9SeS39PRbw8PHGp9wpv39\"}"`.

Comment: Here my concern is `"{\"op\":\"addr_sub\", \"addr\":\"65SQr6sh9SeS39PRbw8PHGp9wpv39\"}` this one is using to receive new transactions for a specific bitcoin address, but i not receive any notification for transaction.